# CSS script not working correctly

Tags: css

CODE:
http://pastebin.com/b7W8rBGA

It always says your on the home tab even when your not you can see it live here
http://www.rewindpvp.com

I don't understand why it always says your on the home tab.

Comment: Please learn how to indent and properly layout your code. Not many (if any) of us are willing to decipher minified code.

But your problem is simple: You have the `active` class applied to the home list item, indicating that the active item is "Home".  I don't see scripts involved either

Comment: And put minimal example code IN the question that will reproduce the problem. If we don't have the code to reproduce ourselves locally, we really don't want to help. (Most of us at least).

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it's a css-issue. It has to do with your script. If you click on a link, the "home" tab still has the id "Active" ...

can you post the script?

Comment: Well then what do I put other than active?

Comment: You can use a jQuery Script for example: $(#cssmenu li).on("click", function() { $(#cssmenu li).removeClass("active"); $(this).addClass("active"); }); to change the active class to the other element... EDIT: still, I don't think that this will solve your problem, you might have to use JSON or AJAX, because I think your page reloads on click... OR you use PHP to write the id into the link each time the page loads...